# OpenCV Mat on the heap

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am a little confused with how Mat objects work.

From what I understand most Mat costructors/methods avoid copying the actual data. I happened to try the following

```
float *data = new float[6];
... //initialize data
Mat M = Mat(2, 3, CV_32F, data);
Mat Mt = M.t();
cout << Mt;
```

Now if I introduce a `delete` command like this:

```
float *data = new float[6];
... //initialize data
Mat M = Mat(2, 3, CV_32F, data);
delete data; // <----
Mat Mt = M.t();
cout << Mt;
```

then cout prints garbage, as expected.

If however the `delete` is introduced after the `Mat Mt=M.t();` line as below:

```
float *data = new float[6];
... //initialize data
Mat M = Mat(2, 3, CV_32F, data);
Mat Mt = M.t();
delete data; // <----
cout << Mt;
```

then cout prints everything correctly, which is surprising to me, since `M.t()` is not supposed to copy the data elsewhere.

So my question is twofold:

1) Since `data` is stored on the heap, am I right in assuming that `M` and `Mt` are also on the heap ("pointing" to the same data)?

2) If the answer to the above question is yes, why isn't `Mt` influenced by deleting `data`?

Comment: "since M.t() is not supposed to copy the data" - only as long as you're inside a MatExpr, where some template trick can just swap rows and cols. M.t().t() would not do a copy, but M.t() has to do in the end.

Comment: Thank you berak. So `M.t()` does some copying in the end. Doesn't that mean that I have to delete it as well to avoid memory leaks? Something like `delete &Mt`?

Comment: no, you don't have to delete Mt, Mat's are refcounted and take care of themselves. you *will* have to delete[] data though.

Comment: A final question: Can I return Mt to a parent function, after `delete data` (as in the second case) without a problem?

Comment: in the second case you delete data *before* making a copy (either by clone() or t()) - this is problematic.

Comment: No, I meant the second case of using `delete` (i.e. the third case overall)...